# Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно согласовать

Tags: согласование

Предложение (вернее, отрывок) такое: "...перечень норм и требований к работе..." Как тут правильно согласовать? "Требований к работе" - это нормально, но не "норм". В общем, я запуталась.)))
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильное управление при однородных членах предложения характерно для канцелярской речи: «в соответствии и на основе утвержденного плана», «руководство и контроль за распределением гуманитарной помощи». В данном случае ошибка объясняется терминологической спаянностью "норм и требований", которые в текстах обычно стоят рядом.

Варианты исправления: перечень рабочих норм и требований,  перечень норм работы и требований к ней.

Более вольные варианты, зависящие от контекста: перечень норм работы и требований к ее качеству, перечень норм чего-то (деятельности, выработки) и требований к работе, перечень каких-то (например, санитарных, плановых) норм и требований к работе, перечень рабочих норм и требований к качеству.